# Is it possible to make this python3 code 1 line using a functional approach?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
grid = []
for i in range(height):
    line = input()  # width characters, each either 0 or .
    row = []
    for j in range(width):
        row.append(line[j] == '0')
    grid.append(row)
```

Is it possible to change this into one line with functional programming? If so, how?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't: `grid = [[char == '0' for _, char in zip(range(width), input())] for _ in range(height)]`. Instead of trying to one-line your code, you should go the opposite direction: Add some input validation that shows an error message if the user input has fewer or more than `width` characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this as provided by @Aran-Fey in comments:

```
grid = [[char == '0' for _, char in zip(range(width), input())] for _ in range(height)]
```

But it is not reccomended and makes your code harder to understand.